# Make SQL Intellisense know the current database

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, ssms

How do I make SQL Server Managment Studio Intellisense know what is the current database in use, i.e. I want to be able to do the following

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.dbo.Table
```

with intellisense.

**UPDATE**

Just confirm, I already had the currentdatabase selected, i.e. I don't have master database shown in the bottom left corner.

Comment: i think you cant. You have to use the full qualified table name to access a table in an other database.

This is because you can have the same tablename in multiple databases

Comment: intellisense automatically does the same

Comment: `you need to manually select from drop down list present at top left corner.. this is one way to specify what DB you are using`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes adding

```
Use DatabaseName
Go
```

To the top of your script file and executing it will do the job. Other than that, the suggetsions on Aaron Bertrands answer provide other ways to fix the intellisense.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. Wierdly I think that "GO" statement actually makes the difference.

Comment: Huh? [There are plenty of things you can do to make IntelliSense work when it doesn't seem to](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/).

Comment: When Intellisense "doesn't want to work" it usually means that you are referring to an object that was created since you last opened SSMS. Now if only there was some sort of blog post explaining this further and offering tips to deal with this....

Comment: @Zane, `ctrl+shift+R` as stated in Aaron's post fixes that.

Comment: @OGHaza That's kind of the joke I was going for.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is the accepted answer if, according to the edit, the OP `already had the currentdatabase selected`.

Comment: @Zane Ha, I didn't read the link and assumed you had checked that blog post and found no solution ;) I was referring to his answer below - slow of me I admit.

Comment: Never found that link before. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you specify `USE DatabaseName;` first, then it will be automatic. Otherwise, no, IntelliSense shouldn't lead you to believe there is a table with that name in the current database - it can't read your mind and know which other database you're thinking about.

If you are in the current database and IntelliSense still doesn't seem to work, first make sure IntelliSense is enabled (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, or hit the "IntelliSense Enabled" icon on the toolbar when the query window has focus), and also hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to update the local IntelliSense cache (it won't always see objects that were created or renamed recently, because it has a lazy loading mechanism (to avoid hammering your server with metadata requests)).

A host of [other troubleshooting tips here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: @IgorShch Your update seems to conflict with the accepted answer. If you had the right database already selected (which is what your update states), how does the accepted answer help solve the problem?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that pre-edit you said "hit ctrl+shift+R to enable intellisense" which was incorrect

Comment: @OGHaza no, it never said that. That might be what you read but I guarantee you I know enough about Management Studio that I would not suggest Ctrl + Shift + R enables IntelliSense.

Comment: Edit history groups edits by 5 minute intervals. Just as you can correct a post within the first 5 minutes and no one will ever be able to prove your original answer was wrong.

Comment: @OGHaza are we seriously still talking about this? I didn't write what you suggested I did, even for a second. You read it wrong. Period. Move on with your life already. Since I wrote the article we're all talking about, do you really think I would get something like that so fundamentally wrong?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : hi sir !! i read your blogs i think they are very informative !! this is the very first case were i'm seeing a answer with less votes has a green tick mark !!

Comment: Apologise for the misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I really don't know.. I run the same "use" statement that I have run several times before I created the topic.. The only difference was that I added "GO" and the end. And it worked. Really, I was going to attach a screenshot to the initial question showing that I have the current database selected, but decided not to. 

I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @IgorShch You have to **execute** the `USE` command, not just type it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you Aaron.. Your kindness knows no bounds