# Adding table to existing database in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I can create a table with:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

But let's say I already have a database called "Northwind" and I want to add this table to that database. How do I do that? Running that script just creates it under "default" database under "Master"...

Comment: You should avoid create new tables on 'master', move to your own database. First create it, then, on SSMS, write `use Northwind` (and execute this sentence). Don't forgot to drop table on master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this !! this adds the table Persons to the required database `Northwind` in your case

[read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400672/make-sql-intellisense-know-the-current-database/20400825#comment30465173_20400825)

```
    use [NorthWind]
    go

    CREATE TABLE Persons
    (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
    );
```

Comment: @Dimo happy 2 help !!

Answer (score 1):

:) Did you select "Northwind"?
If you create that table in a programming language, assume Java, in the connection you have to specify which DB you want to connect to.

If you want to create table in SQL editor of a DBMS, you just need to select "Northwind" using this statement:
`use Northwind;`